# Redis vs Memcached for serving JSON on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, backbone.js, memcached, redis

I have a single page app (Rails + Backbone.js + Postgres on Heroku), and as some of my queries are starting to slow down for users with lots of data (there are multiple queries per object), I want to start caching the JSON I'm sending the client.

I'm already using Redis with Resque, so I'm not sure if I should be using the same redis instance for both Resque and general data caching.  Is that a reason to go with Memcached?

I guess I'm looking for general input from those with experience with either so I can quickly decide on one of the two and start caching stuff (sorry if a clear-cut answer cannot be given).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both will cache strings just fine. Although I think that using redis for a simple cache  is an overkill. I'd go with memcached.

[Blog post](http://antirez.com/post/redis-as-LRU-cache.html) from Salvatore on caching with Redis.

Comment: Thank a bunch.  Quick question:  can memcached handle sorting or grabbing a limited amount of the data?  E.G. I'll want to grab different data if the user wants to sort by 'name' rather than date.  And only grab the first 200 objects if a user (someday) has 1000+ of them.

Comment: I think you should handle it in the application. Pre-sort by different keys and store to separate keys (probably in chunks of 200, to facilitate that paging).